# Select specific date in MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, date, select, monthcalendar

Is it possible to use a variable to automatically locate a certain date in a month calendar?

```
DateTime example = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014");

//Automatically select 1 January 2014 in the calendar
//(i.e. The date corresponding to the example variable above)
```

Comment: When would you want it to be triggered? every system tick? automatically is a very loose term and your missing some research effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [MonthCalendar.SetDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
DateTime example = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014"); 
monthCalendar.SetDate(example);
```